# How to build the space BTOP

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Can anybody explain how is the procedure for building the space BTOP, which classifies microbundles of topological manifold ? Is there any good (and easy to read) references on this subject ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Cheers...